# React Hooks state is not updating with correct output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am using React Hooks. I am trying to sort the data that I fetch from an API and update the state with the newly sorted data.

```
const [runs, setRuns] = useState({
    runs: [],
  });
const [altConcentrationRuns, setAltConcentrationRuns ] = useState({
    altConcentrationRuns : []
  })

async function handleRuns() {
    getRuns().then((result) => {
    
      setRuns(result.rows);
      setFilteredRuns(result.rows);

      //function to sort data according to column header/property
      
      const sortRowsByProperty = (property, direction) => {
        return result.rows.sort(function(a,b) { 
          var A = Object.keys(a)[0];
          var B = Object.keys(b)[0];
          if(direction == "ascending") {
                return (a[A][property] - b[B][property]);
              } else if(direction == "descending") {
                return b[B][property] - a[A][property];
              }
          });
        } 
        setAltConcentrationRuns(sortRowsByProperty('altConcentration', 'ascending'));
        //not updating, only showing runs 

      
      setIsLoading(false);
      
      
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    handleRuns();
    
  }, []);
  console.log('runs', altConcentrationRuns);
```

When I console log my output, I don't get the sorted data, only the original data (result.rows). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: can you add what logs you're getting in the console?

Comment: an array of objects that aren't sorted by altConcentration but is the original array of fetched data (runs)

Comment: A screenshot please :)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Ib9cNbF https://imgur.com/a/R5BgY1J

Comment: `altConcentration` is indeed a string, you can't substruct strings, so you should follow @xdumaine advice. Also, sort mutates the original array, so when it is sorted, it'll be sorted everywhere

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem in your code. you are initializing your state in the wrong way.

```
const [runs, setRuns] = useState([]);
const [altConcentrationRuns, setAltConcentrationRuns ] = useState([])
```

This is how your state should be initialized. docs for [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your sorting function. In JS to sort items, it's common practice to return `-1` when `a < b`, `0` when `a == b` and `1` when `a > b`. You can often omit the `==` condition and just return `-1` or `1`

```js
if (direction === "ascending") {
   return a[A][property] < b[B][property] ? -1 : 1
} else if (direction === "descending") {
   return a[A][property] < b[B][property] ? 1 : -1
}
```

This can be optimized further, but keeping it similar to your code for understandability.

Comment: thanks but it still isn't sorted. and I tested my function on other data, and it sorted fine.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Could you elaborate? You're not _required_ to return `-1`, `0` or `1` but those align with the required `negative, 0 positive` in the requirement. I did say _should_ because this is a best practice. Returning `a[A][property] - b[B][property]` only works on numbers, but `<` operator works on strings as well.

Comment: From your answer it appears that the sort function can only work with -1, 0 and 1, that is not the case, you can use any positive and negative numbers

Comment: I agree with your comment, but I was commenting on your answer, not the comment :)

Comment: It's a good point about strings, that will result in `NaN` which will not sort anything.